# inactivityTimer: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.sendActivities(): Unable to send activity as Streaming connection is closed, Microsoft Bot Framework / DLS

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot, speech

I use Channel Direct Line Speech with my bot  but when 15 minutes pass and the user does not interact with the bot in the webchat, the following error occurs:

unhandled error: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.sendActivities(): Unable to send activity as Streaming connection is closed.
inactivityTimer: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.sendActivities(): Unable to send activity as Streaming connection is closed.

I need to restart the connection, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognitive Services Speech tokens are only valid for 10 mins. Per their REST API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#how-to-use-an-access-token), you can get a new token at any time, however they recommend using the same token for 9 mins to reduce network traffic and latency. For clarity, exchanging tokens shouldn't affect the performance of the speech service. At least, it hasn't for me, yet.